# JavaScript libraries for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Are there competitors or alternatives to [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), which is still in active development?

Comment: Dont use a js library for mobile. Do it by hand, its faster. Libraries are slow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/ is probably the most complete product at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

- **iphone-universal**  - CSS/HTML framework for iPhone web development. Contains the iPhone-like Chat Balloons just like SMS on the iPhone (GPL)
- **iUI** - make iPhone-feeling interfaces
- **iWebKit** - Quick and easy iphone-like web framework, great documentation (LGPL).
- **Jo** - a lightweight JavaScript framework for HTML5 apps, build with PhoneGap in mind
- **JQTouch** - JQuery Plugin for Making iPhone-like apps
- **Magic Framework** - make fast and smooth iPhone-feeling apps with native-feeling widgets, lists, etc. Also provides an easy HTML5 db storage interface.
- **qooxdoo** - Universal JavaScript framework for creating apps for a wide range of platforms, from mobile apps on smartphones and tablets to desktop-style RIAs.
  Safire
- **iZillow** JS/CSS framework (MIT License)
- **Sencha Touch** – HTML5/CSS3/Javascript framework with a variety of native-style widgets, flexible theming via SASS/Compass, data feature like models, stores, and proxies.
- **Unify** - HTML5 framework to create native-like applications for smartphones, tablets and desktops
- **CiUI** - CNET iPhone UI
- **Dashcode** - Framework from Apple (only for iPhone)
- **NS Basic/App Studio** - Full IDE, drag and drop designer, program using Visual BASIC or JavaScript.
- **The Dojo Toolkit** - Flexible and extensible JavaScript framework
- **WebApp.Net**
- **xUI** - slimmed down jQuery work-alike

[source](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501579/JavaScript-Libraries)